# Getting ID value of the clicked row in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a table td's set up like this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.WatchListCompetitor)
{
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="" tabindex="0">@item.SentWord</td>
        <td class="sorting_1">@item.Comment</td>
        <td class="sorting_1">@item.Rating</td>
        <td class="sorting_1">@item.SellerFeedback</td>
        <td class="sorting_1 deleteAction"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
        <td class="idRow" style="display:none;" id="@item.WatchListID">@item.WatchListID</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And I've defined an onclick event like this to try to get the idRow value when the "delete action" is triggered...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleteAction').click(function () {

        console.log($(this).closest("td"));
    });
});
```

The result that I get is:

```
Object { length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <td.sorting_1.deleteAction>, 1 more… }
```

How can I fetch the td idRow value when event is triggered?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `closest` to get to the row, then `find` to get to the idRow td:

```
$('.deleteAction').click(function () {
    var $idRowTd = $(this).closest(".odd").find(".idRow");
    var id = $idRowTd.prop("id");
    // use the element and id here
});
```

Always prefer to use `closest` and `find` rather than looking for the siblings: when you change the HTML (for example you wrap an element), the code stays valid. For the same reason it's better to look for a class (for example `".odd"`) than to look for a tag (for example `"tr"`).

Comment: I'm getting object[Object] result like this

Comment: @User987 `$idRowTd.prop('id')`

Comment: $idRowTd.attr('id');

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Works quite nicely, thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @Denys the ID is now undefined in console for some reason

Comment: @User987 There's a problem elsewhere, it works: https://jsbin.com/doforehika/1/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Find the [sibling()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with the class `idRow` and retrieve its `id`

```
$('.deleteAction').click(function () {

    console.log($(this).siblings("td.idRow").attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: @User987 glad to help.. :) happy coding!!

Comment: you too my friend, and happy new year as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleteAction').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.idRow').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.prop()** or **.attr()** of JQuery to get desired paramas.The difference between **attributes** and **properties** can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the **.attr()** method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of **jQuery 1.6**, the **.prop()** method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while **.attr()** retrieves attributes.

```
$('.deleteAction').click(function () {
    var $idRowTd = $(this).closest(".odd").find(".idRow").attr("id"); //Before/upto jQuery 1.6;
var $idRowTd = $(this).closest(".odd").find(".idRow").prop("id");//for jQuery 1.6 and above
});
```